# genymotion UI is broken and shows as mixed up

Tags: genymotion

It's been a while I was using genymotion and there was no problem. But recently when I run it, the UI shows broken like this:

[image]

There's this message in the terminal:

```
(genymotion:14471): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28 (No space left on device)
```

Though I've checked many times and there are lots of space. To be sure, I deleted many files and programs, but it still says that.

And the `genymotion.log` file have these:

```
Nov 9 11:11:43 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 2.5.2 
Nov 9 11:11:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("./genymotion") 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Status: 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Content: "" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Reply error: "Proxy connection refused" ( 99 ) 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] last error msg: "Unknown proxy error" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Error] Network error while retrieving JSON content:  7 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Error] [getGenymotionLastVersion] Bad request: "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to get last Genymotion version number from server:  7 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] Trying to authenticate  "mousa_mk" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] Trying to logout user 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Status: 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Content: "" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Reply error: "Proxy connection refused" ( 99 ) 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] last error msg: "Unknown proxy error" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Error] [login] Login process result: 7 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "1dbae3bf" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 7917 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Checking status of interface "vboxnet0" "192.168.56.1" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] "vboxnet0" is OK 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "dhcpservers") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.4_Ubuntur102546" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.4_Ubuntur102546" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "vms") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "2d9b3a13-d8af-412a-bbeb-e7f713b4b42d") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "76afb120-f753-4474-bbc9-53c18cc77576") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "4f274f87-41ec-4998-9860-224869634750") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "Custom Phone - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Error] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "443b5e7d-fb22-4070-a2ae-1ddcf4ccc1c7") returns 1 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: The object functionality is limited
VBoxManage: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Shared)" at line 253 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp" 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "74ce8294-3c0c-4b8f-a1a6-b443fe0fdcac") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "Google Nexus 4 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("showvminfo", "Google Nexus 4 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280") returns 0 
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
Major opcode: 56 (X_ChangeGC)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
Major opcode: 56 (X_ChangeGC)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:48 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
Major opcode: 56 (X_ChangeGC)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:48 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
Major opcode: 56 (X_ChangeGC)
Resource id:  0x0
Nov 9 11:11:48 [Genymotion] [Warning] X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x0
```

I tried reinstalling genymotion, even removed the `.Genymotion` folder, but had no success.

**Note:** I suspect this happened after upgrading to ubuntu 15.10, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that this has nothing to do with genymotion and the problem is with `Qt` and `gnome`. Some other applications like `VirtualBox` and `GoldenDict` are affected too.

This workaround suppresses it for now:

```
export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Mousa's answer is great.

I'm using Ubuntu, so I find it convenient to have Genymotion in my launcher.  To do that, *and to include the QT workaround*, I've done the following below.

**1.** First I installed Genymotion in `~/opt/genymotion`.  If you installed elsewhere, remember to place.

**2.** Then I created `~/.local/share/applications/genymotion.desktop`:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/33889466
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Genymotion
Comment=Android Emulator
Icon=genymotion
Exec=env QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /home/username/opt/genymotion/genymotion
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Keywords=android;genymotion;emulator;
```

NOTE 1: The QT workardound is in the Exec statement.

NOTE 2: Remember to edit the absolute path to your genymotion exectuable.

**3.** I then copied the Genymotion icon file so it can be found by Unity:

```
cp ~/opt/genymotion/icons/icon.png ~/.local/share/icons/genymotion.png
```

**4.** Now you can find Genymotion in your Unity launcher search.

**5.** (Sometimes it is necessary to re-login in order to have Unity discover your personal changes).

At the time of writing, Skype for Linux is also effected by this QT issue and a similar around can be applied: Simply `locate` its respective `*.desktop` file, copy it into your `~/.local/share/applications/` folder, give the app a new `Name` (e.g. prepend "QT-fix") and insert the above fix in `Exec`.